# How to set swing threads as daemon?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Is there any solution to set the swing's threads as `daemon`?
Considering a application which starts a copying operation, meanwhile shows the process by a `jframe`, so I want to set the swing ui thread as daemon, in order to jvm kills the thread once the copying thread gets terminated.

Comment: What do you mean by "swing's threads"?

Comment: `in order to jvm kills the thread once the copying thread gets terminated.` That's not deamon thread do.

Comment: Why not just make the background task terminate the application once it's finished, such as in the `done()` of a `SwingWorker`?

Comment: Are you saying you want to make the EDT daemon so the program exits when your worker thread ends? Why not exit the program yourself? System.exit...closing the frame, etc.

Comment: the thread which handles swing ui. @MarounMaroun

Comment: simply close the JFrame programmatically when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The Swing EDT is already what you consider a "daemon" - after you dispose/hide all Swing elements, the thread will silently exit. You can read more about [AWT Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html), which states that ...

> [with] the current implementation, AWT terminates all its helper threads allowing the application to exit cleanly when the following three conditions are true:
>
> - There are no displayable AWT or Swing components.
> - There are no native events in the native event queue.
> - There are no AWT events in java EventQueues.

The same is true for Swing.

Comment: Um, the EDT is not daemon.

Comment: Hence the "what you consider" phrasing. The behaviour of the EDT is already what he is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, just making sure. It's important to be as correct as possible so you can't be misunderstood. Something like *"Although the EDT is not daemon, its behavior is very much like it because..."* would be more clear.

Comment: Thread.currentThread().isDaemon() returns false if executed on the EDT. "daemon thread" in java means that the JVM does not wait for them on shutdown. The EDT not being a daemon thread means the JVM considers it a user thread and will wait till graphics have been closed before it shuts down (unless forced with System.exit() which you really should never even think about using).